# WMIC How to pass arguments/ parameters with exe

Tags: wmic

I want to call exe from remote system using WMIC direct command. for that I prepare one command here

```
WMIC /NODE:"RemoteSys" /USER:"domain\username" /PASSWORD:"XXXXXXXXX" PROCESS CREATE "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Product\productapp.exe"
```

But issue here is this productapp.exe is expecting an arguments/ parameters like "  -p PlantA   "

Question here is How to pass it ?

I tried many alternate ways but all fails like:

WMIC /NODE:"RemoteSys" /USER:"domain\username" /PASSWORD:"XXXXXXXXX" PROCESS CREATE "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Product\productapp.exe" -p PlantB
Output: Invalid Verb Switch

WMIC /NODE:"RemoteSys" /USER:"domain\username" /PASSWORD:"XXXXXXXXX" PROCESS CREATE "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Product\productapp.exe" "-p PlantB"
Output: Invalid format. Hint:  =  [, ].

Don't know what is paramlist & How to use that.

Can anyone help me here ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar with MATLAB. What you could try is opening a command prompt and executing the program with parameters from that command prompt.

```
WMIC /NODE:"RemoteSys" /USER:"username" /PASSWORD:"XXX" PROCESS CALL CREATE "cmd.exe /c cd C:/Program Files (x86)/Company/Product/ & productapp.exe -p PlantB"
```